# Why this bibtex entry give me a 'undefined control sequence'?

Tags: bibtex

Having this bibtex entry in `file.bib`:

```
@ARTICLE{Silva2007,
  author = {Newton José Rodrigues da Silva and Jean-Eudes Beuret and Olivier
Mikolasek and Guy Fontenelle and Lionel Dabbadie and Maria Inez Espagnoli Geraldo Martins},
  title = {Modelo Teórico de Análise de Políticas Públicas e Desenvolvimento},
  journal = {Revista de Economia Agrícola},
  year = {2007},
  volume = {54},
  pages = {43-66},
  number = {2},
  month = {jul/dez},
  file = {Silva2007.pdf:Silva2007.pdf:PDF},
  owner = {vinicius},
  school = {Universidade do Estado de São Paulo},
  timestamp = {2012.02.07},
  url = {http://www.cati.sp.gov.br/Cati/_tecnologias/piscicultura/ASP-PISCICULTURA.pdf}
}
```

Citing like this on `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{abnt}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{abnt-UFPR}
\usepackage{abntcite}
\usepackage{color}

(..)

\cite{Silva2007}

(..)

\renewcommand{\-}{\penalty 0}
\bibliography{tg}
```

And compiling it like:

```
pdflatex file.tex
bibtex file.aux
pdflatex file.tex
pdflatex file.tex
```

Will prompt on the following error:

```
[26]) (./tg.bbl [27] [28]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ti\-.sp\-.gov\-.br\-/Cati\-/\underl 
                                                  ine{\^^M}tecnologias\-/pis...
l.215 ...logias/piscicultura/ASP-PISCICULTURA.pdf}
                                              .}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error is related to the `_` in your `url` field. I'd add `\usepackage{url}` to the document preamble and replace

```
url = {http://www.cati.sp.gov.br/Cati/_tecnologias/piscicultura/ASP-PISCICULTURA.pdf}
```

by

```
url = {\url{http://www.cati.sp.gov.br/Cati/_tecnologias/piscicultura/ASP-PISCICULTURA.pdf}}
```

in your `.bib` file.

My output:

[image: My output]

Hope it helps. `:)`

**Edit:** As pointed by Legolas in the comments, some bibliography styles already manage `url` fields nicely, so the `\url` trick is not needed.

For `abntcite`, there's a remark in the manual to load `hyperref` before `abntcite`, so the `url` fields will be correctly displayed. It's a matter of adding

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{abntcite}
```

and everything will work as expected, without the need of changing the `url` field in your `.bib` file.

My new output:

[image: New output]

Comment: I think this does depend on the bibliography package you use. So, if you were ever to change to, for example, biblatex, you may need to revert these changes. Nevertheless, this is the right answer.

Comment: @Legolas: Yes, you are absolutely right. `:)` There are other biblography styles that manage URLs nicely, which IMHO is the way to go. In this particular case I'm afraid the OP needs to stick with `abntcite`, since it's one of the standards for academic documents in Brazil. Sadly, `abntcite` seems to not have a URL fallback, so I'd go with `\url`. `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Paulo. I forgot to say that I've seen this solution before, and that I'm using `Jabref` to manage the bibliography. I would like to keep a "clean" `url` field so this tool can build links and so. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Vinicius: Sure! See my new edit. `:)`

Comment: Well, @Paulo. I'm already using `hyperref`, and still getting the same error. Actually, I just added all my preamble to my question, so maybe you can figure out what's causing the error. I tried different order combinations to load these packages and also removed all packages but `abntcite` and `hyperref` in the order you told me. I got nowhere with all this. Any hints would be a great help.

Comment: @Vinicius: I'm deeply sorry, but I can't reproduce the error, even with the new preamble. `:(` Your code works for me. Maybe if you could add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, we might be able to track the error down. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

What helped me in a similar case is the protection of fragile makros, by `\protect\url{...}` which [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner) explained here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51052/110394

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Where will you place the `\protect` in the given issue? Have you tried it? The issue in this question is a problem with `_` you can not protect.  The solution here is using an bibliographystyle able to handle `\url`s correctly ...