# Avoiding "\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument." in a custom environment

Tags: environments, captions, urls

I have a document I'm trying to render using two classes -- my university's dissertation `.cls`, and `tufte-latex` (my uni's styleguide is ugly, and I want to make a pretty-print version for my own gratification).  I've written a shim for `tufte-latex`'s `\sidefig` command, which reads like so:

```
\newenvironment{sidefig}%
{\begin{figure}}%
{\end{figure}}%
```

This works, except in the case where I need to use `\url` inside `\caption`, to cite an image source, ie:

```
\begin{sidefig}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{graphics/foobar}
  \caption{This is the foobar graphic. Source: \url{http://foo.bar/baz} \label{fig:foobar}}
\end{sidefig}
```

This renders fine through `tufte-latex`'s own `sidefig` environment, but errors with the following error text using my shim.

```
[1] <graphics/foobar.png, id=34, 233.07076pt x 310.761pt>
<use graphics/foobar.png>
! Undefined control sequence.
\Url Error ->\url used in a moving argument. 

l.36 ...p://foo.bar/baz} \label{fig:foobar}}
```

Any idea how I can modify my shim environment to avoid this error?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Moving argument entries may require protection. In this case, use `\protect\url{...}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering\rule{150pt}{100pt}
  \caption{This is the foobar graphic. Source: \protect\url{http://foo.bar/baz} \label{fig:foobar}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `\protect` do?

Comment: @TahaMagdy: See [What is the purpose of `\protect`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12698/5764)

Answer (score 1):

Works in the IEEE paper footnote as well.

> `\thanks{This letter has supplementary downloadable material available at \protect\url{https://}, provided by the authors.}`
> [image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/231746)